# Struct parameter deduction in D

Tags: templates, d, type-inference

Just wondering why this does not compile. I thought the compiler could infer types for a parameterized struct?

```
void main() {
    auto arr = Arr([1,2,3]);
}

struct Arr(T) {
    private T[] data;
}
```

Error:

```
junk.d(25): Error: struct junk.Arr(T) is not a function template
junk.d(25): Error: struct junk.Arr(T) cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(int[])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code of the form:

```
auto arr = Arr([1,2,3]);
```

is a call to the constructor of `Arr` when `Arr` is a `struct`. In this case, there is no explicit constructor. If there was, it could have been templated, and parameter inference does work for templated constructors. Since there is no constructor, the parameters will be used to initialize the fields of `Arr` in the order they are declared. But, of course, `Arr` is a template, so the type to construct is not yet known.

If you think there should be parameter inference for this case, consider the following:

```
struct Arr(T)
{
    static if(is(T == bool))
        BitArray data;
    else
        T[] data;
}
```

In the above example, the types (and it could be the order too) of the fields are not known until the template is instantiated... so how would it infer?

The template has to be explicitly instantiated:

```
auto arr = Arr!int([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: What would be required in an explicit constructor? `this(T)(T a){data = a;}` doesn't do it. Is this bug relevant? http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6082

Comment: 6082 is an enhancement request, not a bug report. It's not currently possible to use constructor arguments to fill in the template parameters of the surrounding type. Note that your example there is different anyway, because the constructor itself is a template and its parameters are not related to the parameters of the surrounding type template. It will indeed have IFTI like I said, but it doesn't help your particular case.

Comment: Ah, last night I did realize the constructor was using different parameters (shadowing?), but forgot. Well, I hope the feature is reached sooner or later.